# pandas date_time not converting the string into date format

Tags: python

I have data of Jan-91 (mmm-YY) format. I am trying to convert is using pandas date_time function with code -
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format = '%ddd-%YY')
However getting the error as
time data 'Jan-91' does not match format '%ddd-%YY' (match)

time data 'Jan-91' does not match format '%ddd-%YY' (match)

I am trying to expecting the output should be DD-MM_YYYY format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/convert-string-jun-1-2005-133pm-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

your datetime format is a little off. Instead of %ddd-%YY it should read "%b-%y". i.e. the code snippet should read:

```
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format = '%b-%y')
```

If you look at the [documentation for pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), under `format`, it says that it uses `strftime` syntax to get the date format. Under [strftime and strptime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), you will see the correct format codes are %b for a 3 letter month abbreviation, and %y for a zero-padded year without a century.

Then, to get the date into your desired format, you will need a second line to reassign the `Month` column:

```
data['Month'] = data['Month'].dt.strftime(date_format = '%d-%m_%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

According [the Pandas documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#:%7E:text=The%20strftime%20to%20parse%20time), the `format` argument is only for parsing not for the destination format. So to get your desired output, you have to first parse into the default format, and then use the `` to produce your expected format:

```py
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'])
data['Month'] = data['Month'].dt.strftime('%d-%m_%Y')
```